# Mouse Gestures Aren't Working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T480 and I am running regular Ubuntu 18.04. Sometimes, the trackpad gestures stop working, and I have to restart my computer to fix them. When I say trackpad gestures, I mean two-finger right click and scrolling. I also have tap-to-click disabled, but even when I enable it, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have the same machine, same OS, same exact problem. I have noted that a logout and log in doesn't fix the problem. I have been struggling to pinpoint when exactly it the trackpad gestures stop working because I often use a USB mouse, so I don't notice until I try to use the trackpad. Have you identified any association with a software or event that you do when the gestures stop working and then require restart to fix?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I only say this just now. I fixed it by updating to Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating to Ubuntu 19.10.